# passing name of generated jar file from Maven pom.xml to Dockerfile

Tags: java, maven, dockerfile, spotify

I have a java/hibernate/jpa/maven project that I am trying to convert so that it (the .jar file created from the project) is part of a Docker Image. I am also using the Spotify plugin.

Below, for the following Docker command

> ```
> ADD <full_path_of_generated_file>.jar app.jar
> ```

The value **full_path_of_generated_file**  is generated from the pom.xml file (on the Maven side). This information is needed in order for Docker to generate the image properly.

How can one get the name of the generated file over to the Dockerfile?

TIA

**Plugin area of the Maven pom.xml file**

```
<plugins>
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
        <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>

        <configuration>
            <imageName>apx/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
            <dockerDirectory>${project.basedir}/docker</dockerDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>2.6</version> -->
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>analyze</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <failBuild>true</failBuild>
                    <ignoreDirect>false</ignoreDirect>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>

            <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>ccinfw.MainApplication</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
</plugins>

[... snip ...]

<artifactId>ccinf</artifactId>
```

**Below is a copy of the Dockerfile being used**

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD <full_path_of_generated_file>.jar app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Comment: I assume your packaging of the pom is either "jar" or you don't have given a package tag?

Comment: I only incorporated part of the pom.xml file (to keep things brief). Yes, a .jar file is being created for use with Docker image.

Comment: The simplest thing I can think of is: `<build><finalName>WhatEver.jar</finalName>...` and change the `ADD target/WhatEver.jar app.jar` ?

Comment: BTW: The configurations you have defined in your pom file for maven-jar-plugin do not exist...Nor do you need to do an executions. Only give the configuration part for the mainClass...no finalName in plugin configuration etc.

Answer (score 3):

Inside pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/docker</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Make sure to place the Dockerfile in the location mentioned in pom, so that it could build and copy the Dockerfile with replacing the references dynamically.

[image]

Inside Dockerfile

```
ADD @project.artifactId@-@project.version@.jar app.jar
```

credits: https://github.com/vmudigal/microservices-sample

Comment: This credits have `ADD service-three.jar app.jar` in his project executable `ADD @project.artifactId@-@project.version@.jar app.jar` not working

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was passing the name of the final artifact (e.g. something_or_other-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar) as an argument ([ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)) into the Dockerfile.

Inside pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
        ...
        <configuration>
        ...
            <buildArgs>
                <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
            </buildArgs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Then, inside of Dockerfile

```
    # insert other Dockerfile stuff here and then...

    ARG JAR_FILE
    ADD target/${JAR_FILE} app.jar
    ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```